How to prove that an expected quantity converges to its actual quantity?
This is one of the only links I have been able to find on the justification behind why the observed fisher information can be replaced with the expected fisher information : Convergence rate of empirical Fisher information matrix .  While the answer was quite good in this question, there were still some gaps in my unexperienced mind, and I wanted to try and fill in these gaps. I tried to do it myself:
Define:
$$ \begin{align}
& I_n(\theta) = -\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \log L(\theta) \text{ (Observed Fisher Information)} \\
& I(\theta) = E\left[-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \log L(\theta)\right] \text{ (Expected Fisher Information)}
\end{align} $$
Step 1: Express the log-likelihood in terms of individual observations
$$ \log L(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log f(X_i|\theta) $$
Step 2: Express the observed Fisher information
$$ I_n(\theta) = -\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \log L(\theta) = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \log f(X_i|\theta) $$
Step 3: Define some new random variable $Y_i = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \log f(X_i|\theta)$
Step 4: Express the difference we want to prove approaches $0$
$$ I_n(\theta) - I(\theta) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i - E[Y_i] $$
Step 5: Apply Central Limit Theorem
$$ \begin{align}
\sqrt{n}(I_n(\theta) - I(\theta)) &= \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i - E[Y_i]\right) \\[10pt]
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - E[Y_i]) \\[10pt]
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i
\end{align} $$
Where $Z_i = Y_i - E[Y_i]$ are independent, identically distributed random variables with $E[Z_i] = 0$ and $Var(Z_i) = Var(Y_i) = \sigma^2$.
By the Central Limit Theorem:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma^2) \text{ as } n \to \infty $$
Therefore:
$$ \sqrt{n}(I_n(\theta) - I(\theta)) \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma^2) \text{ as } n \to \infty $$
Step 6: Convert to a statement about convergence in probability
I really struggled with this part. To convert from convergence in distribution to convergence in probability, I think we can can use Slutsky's theorem. First, let's define:
$$ X_n = \sqrt{n}(I_n(\theta) - I(\theta)) $$
We know from Step 5 that $X_n \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma^2)$.
Now, let's consider:
$$ \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}} = I_n(\theta) - I(\theta) $$
By Slutsky's theorem, if $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{p} c$ (where $c$ is a constant), then $X_n Y_n \xrightarrow{d} cX$.
In our case, $X_n \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{p} 0$ (since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a deterministic sequence converging to 0).
Therefore:
$$ \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}} = I_n(\theta) - I(\theta) \xrightarrow{d} 0 \cdot N(0, \sigma^2) = 0 $$
I am not sure if this is the correct interpretation of Slutsky's theorem, but in my eyes it would suggest that:
$$ I_n(\theta) - I(\theta) \xrightarrow{p} 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty $$
Step 7: To conclude, we can show that:
$$ -\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \log L(\theta) - E\left[-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \log L(\theta)\right] \xrightarrow{p} 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty $$
Th proves that the difference between the observed Fisher information and the expected Fisher information converges in probability to $0$ as the sample size increases.


Note: I decided to add a PS example explaining the difference between Observed Fisher Information and the Expected Fisher Information . In short, the expected fisher information is always the same , regardless of the data. Whereas the Observed Fisher Information depends on the data.
Observed Fisher Information:
$$I_n(\theta) = -\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log L(\theta)$$
Expected Fisher Information:
$$I(\theta) = E\left[-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log L(\theta)\right]$$


Consider a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\theta$.
For a sample of size $n$, the log-likelihood function is:
$$\log L(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n [x_i \log \theta + (1-x_i) \log (1-\theta)]$$
The second derivative of the log-likelihood is:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log L(\theta) = -\sum_{i=1}^n \left[\frac{x_i}{\theta^2} + \frac{1-x_i}{(1-\theta)^2}\right]$$
The observed Fisher information is:
$$I_n(\theta) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[\frac{x_i}{\theta^2} + \frac{1-x_i}{(1-\theta)^2}\right]$$
The expected Fisher information for a Bernoulli distribution is:
$$I(\theta) = E\left[\frac{X}{\theta^2} + \frac{1-X}{(1-\theta)^2}\right] = \frac{1}{\theta(1-\theta)}$$
Now, consider a specific sample. Suppose $n = 5$ and we observe the sample $(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)$.
The observed Fisher information for this sample is:
$$I_n(\theta) = \frac{1}{5}\left[\frac{3}{\theta^2} + \frac{2}{(1-\theta)^2}\right]$$
This is clearly different from the expected Fisher information $\frac{1}{\theta(1-\theta)}$ for any value of $\theta$.
The observed Fisher information depends on the specific sample drawn, while the expected Fisher information is an average over all possible samples. As sample size approaches infinity, it seems these converge:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n(\theta) = I(\theta)$$

From your question I understood that you are interested in how to prove that the observed Fisher information converges in distribution to the Fisher information, i.e. $I_n(\theta) \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} I(\theta)$. I hope that I understood your question right. I want to answer it and give some comments:

I assume we have $iid$ univariate random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ at our hands. Furthermore I will follow Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) and write $I(\theta) = -\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} f_X(X,\theta) |\theta \right)$. This is different from the definition you have given (Yours is in terms of the likelihood. I think you have to adjust your definition. You either have to substitute the likelihood by the density, as in the definition here or add a $\frac{1}{n}$ as in $I_n$)
Then I will write $I_n(\theta) = -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} f_X(X,\theta)$. In the $iid$ setting this coincides with the definition for the observed Fisher information you have given (as you have written in step 2). Then note that $\mathbb{E}(I_n(\theta)) = I(\theta)$.


In general, if you want to show that something converges to its expectation, the LLN (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#) is the way to go. For convergence in $p$, the WLLN (Khinchin) is sufficient and we only need that the random variables $Y_i = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} f_X(X_i,\theta)$ are $iid$ and have finite mean. Then the WLLN give you the desired result.

Regarding the CLT and the other question you cited (Convergence rate of empirical Fisher information matrix): There the CLT is used to derive the rate of convergence (instead of just showing that it does converge). Using the CLT, you can show that $I_n(\theta) - I(\theta)$ goes to zero in probability as fast as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ goes to zero.

Your derivation of the result using the CLT and Slutzky is in principle correct, however it is somewhat overshooting because the WLLN is sufficient.

Bernoulli Example: For finite $n$, the observed and true Fisher information wont necessarilly coincide. To see that everything is alright with the Bernoulli example you can rewrite the observed Fisher Information in terms of $a_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$, apply the WLLN to see $a_n \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} \theta$ and then rearrange. Then you will get the (expected) Fisher information.


So to summarize: to show that $I_n$ converges in $p$ to $I$ you really only need the WLLN. If you are interested in the rate of convergence, the CLT can help you.
